# ResourceNameDiscover Class Not Found Exception in axis 1.4

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, wsdl, axis

I am getting below `Exception` when I tried using the Axis 1.4 JAR. The method I invoked is `AxisProperties.setProperty("someString","someString")`

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/discovery/ResourceNameDiscover
```

Comment: As i understand you should add jar to run time env.

Comment: Does the jar contain all the dependencies? If not you have to add the commons jar to classpath.

Comment: I have already included all the dependencies. I am using Intelliji Idea version 13.

Answer (score 1):

Download the commons-discovery.jar and add it to the classspath.

Comment: I have already included all the dependencies. I am using Intelliji Idea version 13

Comment: @GaneshR and you run the application from intelij?

Comment: Yes. I am running the application from intelliji Idea